# cfprocparam is throwing ILLEGAL SYMBOL =;

Tags: coldfusion-11

Upgraded from CF10 to CF11 update 5 ( with hotfix hf1100-3971083.jar )
DB (DB2 v10.2)

getting an error on code that calls a stored proc.

```
Error Executing Database Query.
[Macromedia][DB2 JDBC Driver][DB2]ILLEGAL SYMBOL =;  
The error occurred in ...: line 238
236 :  <cfstoredproc datasource="#application.dsn#" procedure="LIVE.SP" >
237 :     <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIGINT" dbvarname="STOPID" null="yes" />
238 :     <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" dbvarname="POID" null="no" value="#val( qry.id )#" />
239 :  </cfstoredproc>
```

The actual code looks like this - and works fine in CF10....

"qry" IS returning a value for "id"

```
<cfloop query="qry" >

    <cfstoredproc datasource="#application.dsn#" procedure="LIVE.SP" >

        <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIGINT" dbvarname="STOPID" null="yes" />

        <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" dbvarname="POID" null="no" value="#val( qry.id )#" />

    </cfstoredproc>

</cfloop>
```

This happens IF or NOT the 'debugging' is turned on (per hotfix hf1100-3971083.jar)

It seems there are others claiming cfprocparam issues - but the solutions to those issues are not fixing THIS issue.

Any Ideas?

Comment: if it was in the proc - i'd expect it to error in CF10...
But I'll try your suggestion

Comment: hard coding value does not make a difference.

Comment: *If it was in the proc - i'd expect it to error in CF10* Not necessarily. Agreed, it is less likely but ... driver changes could cause differences in behavior.  Can you test the same SQL (with hard coded values) from within a cfquery? I am not familiar with DB2.

Comment: I tried that Leigh, no change. I've tried the hotfix too
I tried renaming the dbvarname="STOPID" to dbvarname="@STOPID"
as someone suggested that change was needed in CF11... ...see my 'answer' for my solution.

Comment: Weird... you should submit a bug report (with a small repro case demonstrating the issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple days of trying multiple suggestions from people.
I removed the "dbvarname" arguments, made sure my arguments were an ordinal match to the procedure, and that gets me past the error.

```
<cfstoredproc datasource="#application.dsn#" procedure="LIVE.SP" >
    <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIGINT" null="yes" />
    <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" null="no" value="#val( qry.id )#" />
</cfstoredproc>
```

This works without error. I can't say I **LIKE** the solution. but oh well.
The other solution that probably would have worked was to use

```
<cfquery...>
    call 'procName' ( arg => value, arg2 => val2 );
</cfquery>
```

however, this is legacy code which hopefully wont exist for more then a year longer (*...hopefully...*). So Im not going to fret about it.